# Why application resource js-file not included to all files when it should to

Tags: grails

I want to include **application.js** to all pages base on main.gsp template, but in some reasons application.js included only in few pages.

Theres my config:
**ApplicationResources.groovy**:

```
modules = {
    application {
        resource url: 'css/common.css'
        resource url: 'js/application.js'
        resource url: 'js/bootbox.min.js'
    }
}
```

**Main** template(main.gsp):

```
...
<r:require modules="application, bootstrap, bootstrap-responsive-css, bootstrap-js"/>
...
```

There's two **.gsp** files which inherited from **main** template:

```
<meta name="layout" content="main"/>
```

But in one page application.js is exist as (/.../static/bundle-bundle_application_defer.js"), but not exist in other.

Difference between files only in custom layout markup, not in ,  and so on.
But files belong to different controllers, may be that where problem is?

So what should i check to understand where the problem is?

Comment: Just as a tip, you should leverage the dependencies of the resources instead of requiring a list of modules.

Comment: +1 @JamesKleeh. Do you `layoutResources` in head and body of `main.gsp` once you require the modules?

Answer (score 1):

I think that all the javascript files are bundled together in one file, you can check it in Firebug

Comment: I'm checked it, by **debugger;** command in chrome, but as i'm said before, cannot reach breakpoint in pages without application.js

Comment: so I understand you see the code in the debugger and you can put a breakpoint it just doesn't hit it, right? so it means the code is there, but it's just not executed - maybe there is some error in the code and it break script execution? try adding `alert('debug');` somewhere in the beginning application.js and see if the alert shows up